# mockito wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I apologize for making another post on this error, but I double checked the other post and ensured it is not the same cause.

I have a `ExploreRepository` class that use a `ExploreService`. The repository implement NetworkBoundResource. I am unit testing repository, use Mockito to mock Service.

```kotlin
class ExploreRepository(
    private val context: Context,
    private val exploreService: ExploreService
) {
    
    suspend fun getProperties(southwest: LatLng, northeast: LatLng, zoomLevel: Float): LiveResource<List<Property>> {
        return object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Property>, SearchProperties>() {


            override suspend fun makeApiCall(): SearchProperties {
                println("exploreService hashcode ${System.identityHashCode(exploreService)}")
                return exploreService.getProperties(context, geoHashList, precision)
            }

        }.asLiveResource()
    }
```

My testExploreRepository class

```kotlin
@Config(sdk = intArrayOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1))
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExploreRepositoryTest {


    ...
    // Subject under test
    private lateinit var exploreRepository: ExploreRepository

    // Use a fake service to be injected into the repository
    private lateinit var mockExploreService: ExploreService

    private lateinit var mockSearchProperties: SearchProperties

    private val context: Application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        mockExploreService = mock()
        exploreRepository = ExploreRepository(context, mockExploreService)
        mockSearchProperties = mock()
    }

    @Test
    fun `should make network service call`() = runBlocking<Unit> {

        // stubbing
        whenever(mockExploreService.getProperties(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(mockSearchProperties)

        val northeast = LatLng( 37.799001, -122.422889)
        val southwest = LatLng( 37.782180, -122.451554)
        val zoomLevel = 10f

        exploreRepository.getProperties(southwest,northeast,zoomLevel)
        println("exploreService hashcode ${System.identityHashCode(mockExploreService)}") // debug line
        verify(mockExploreService, times(1)).getProperties(any(), any(), any())
    }
}
```

I have printed out the exploreService's hashCode.
The `println("exploreService hashcode ${System.identityHashCode(exploreService)}")` inside the makeApiCall() did run.
And I ensured that I am calling the  on the same instance of mock Service inside my repository.
But mockito still throw `Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

Edit: Actually in the test file, with the println() debug line enabled. The error is gone. Without it throw the error. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to test a callback implementation with a coroutine testing strategy. So the test could be finishing before the mock is call inside the callback. Also, you are returning a "LiveResource" from the suspend method, so maybe you should consume that and verify on the return instead of checking the mock, since you do create an object inside the method

Comment: thanks but the repository implementation is not a callback, it is a implementation of the NetworkboundResource abstract class.
NetworkboundResource's constructor will call the makeApiCall function.  even the printlin() inside the makeApiCall function did run.

Comment: You are right about it being a timing issue. If I replace that prinln() with sleep(20), the test pass.
Likely is because we use coroutine suspend in NetworkBoundResource, verify() is called before NetworkBoundResource call makeApiCall()

Comment: Will mark yours as accepted since you are on the right track. thank you.